# How to write logic for apex class to pull all records at first call and then only the records created yesterday?

Tags: apex, webservices, code

I created a web-service class to expose custom object data.

So in the first call we want to pull all the records and then after that we want the records that are created or last modified only yesterday.

Is it possible to write everything in a apex class without modifying the code 2 times ? (like first time to pull all and 2 time to pull only yesterdays records.

**Class** : (I was able to extract only yesterday's records) I want the logic to perform both, any help on this ?

```
global class sampleWsdl {
     global class innClass{
          global String ID;
          global String Name;

          public innClass() {}

          public innClass(String Id,String Name) {
               this.Id= Id;
               this.Name= Name;

          }
     }

        webservice static List<innClass> getSampleData() {

          innClass cls;
          List<innClass> ListClass = new List<innClass>(); 
          for (customObject__c co: [
               select Id,Name from customObject__c Where CreatedDate =: Date.today()-1)]) {
                 cls= new innClass (co.Id,co.Name);
                 ListClass.add(cls);
          }

          return ListClass;
     }
```

Comment: You could pull in all the records and then qualify them when you deserilize your response into your object

Comment: @EricSSH Thanks for your response! Can u please provide sample logic for that ?

Answer (score 3):

There are a few different ways to accomplish what you're looking for.

The important questions to answer here are

- how will my method know when it should return each different data set?
- how will I construct the different data sets I need?

The most common answer to the first question is to add a parameter to your method signature (that is, the `static <returnType> methodName()` bit of your code). The simplest thing you could do is to add a `Boolean` parameter. You could call it `returnAll`

```
webservice static List<innClass> getSampleData(Boolean returnAll) {
    // Code ommitted because it isn't important... yet.
}
```

This isn't the only way to tackle this problem, and it might not even be the best way to do it. It (alone) wouldn't be able to handle things if you later decided that you wanted to return all records, yesterday's records, or records from two days ago. It is, however, simple and effective for this particular case.

Now we move on to constructing the different data sets that you need. What you're looking for is to abstract (or generalize) your code. Abstract code is code that is written once, but can handle different situations. Being able to abstract code is an important skill for a programmer to have.

This too can be approached in more than one way. In this case, I think I'll go with the following plan

- Query your data once, then process it differently depending on the end result that we want

With the query once plan, we need to query for all the data, and then possibly omit some results from it. An example of this would be

```
List<myObject__c> filteredResults = new List<myObject__c>();
Date yesterday = Date.Today().addDays(-1);

for(myObject__c currentInstance :[SELECT Id, CreatedDate FROM myObject__c]){
    if(returnAll){
        filteredResults.add(currentInstance);
    } else {
        if(currentInstance.CreatedDate == yesterday){
            filteredResults.add(currentInstance);
        }
    }
}

return filteredResults;
```

Once again, this isn't the only way to do it, and it's probably not even the best way to do it. It should, however, work for your needs (with appropriate modification to your specific case, of course).

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Derek about adding a parameter to your method to indicate which records to return.  I disagree with his thought on querying for all data and then omitting results. To me this is inefficient.

If the SOQL is capable of only returning the records that I want then I prefer to have it done on the query.

```
webservice static List<innClass> getSampleData(Boolean returnAll) {

    List<innClass> ListClass = new List<innClass>(); 
    for (customObject__c co : getObjects(returnAll)) {
        innClass cls = new innClass (co.Id,co.Name);
        ListClass.add(cls);
    }

    return ListClass;
} 

private static List<CustomObject__c> getObjects(Boolean returnAll){
    String selectClause = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM CustomObject__c';
    String whereClause = 'WHERE LastModifiedDate = YESTERDAY';

    String queryString;

    if( returnAll ){
        queryString = selectClause;
    }else{
        queryString = selectClause +' '+ whereClause;
    }
    return Database.query(queryString);
}
```

Here I am using [Dynamic SOQL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dynamic_soql.htm) to build the query string and only return the desired records.

In the case of only getting records created or last modified yesterday I am filtering on `LastModifiedDate` as this will get both records created yesterday and last modified yesterday.  FInally I am using the [Date Literal](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_dateformats.htm) `YESTERDAY` to specify the date rather than mess around with the Date class/methods

Comment: Yep, I didn't spend any time trying to think up a particularly efficient solution. It was just the first easy solution that came to mind, and with a complexity of O(n) it shouldn't be too terrible (though a query is probably closer to O(1) ).

Comment: @Doug B Thanks for your responese I tried the logic you provided and I am getting error : Variable does not exist: returnAll @ ` for (Deal_Registration__c dr: getObjects(returnAll))` I made the getObjects method to Public but still same error

Comment: @Amar In my answer I didn't include the Boolean variable for your `getSampleData` method.  I have now included it in my answer, which if you copy/pasted would have thrown that error.